# In Flutter, why Scaffold's body can't directly use Row()?

Tags: flutter

If I use Row() instead of Center(), it will not be displayed,just blank.

I expect a music player like layout.
Make 2 Row, the 1st Row contain "LeftMenu" and "Expanded Container" for content .

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to show a _code_ example.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in scaffold gives you the left menu:

```
drawer: const Drawer(
          child: Text("Left Menu")
      ),
```

Putting this inside scaffold body works. Expanded and a row:

```
 Column(
          children: [

            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Center(child: Text("1")),
                )
            ),

            Row(
              children: const [
                Text("1"),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text("2"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace center with row, it probably displays but in the top left corner and not middle. Try to wrap your Row with Center and it should display in the middle. For the row you need to add a mainAxisAlignment.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center (child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children:[ Text('Left menu'),Text('Place container here')]
        ),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the wrong question.
The real problem is: if the ListView is nested by Column, Row, it will not be displayed.
You need to use Expanded or Container on the outside and then nest it with Colmn or Row.